# Magento 2 - Category Thumbail

Tags: magento2, category, thumbnail

I'm currently using $_category->getImageUrl(); to return a category's image. How can I get a smaller thumbnail of the category image? I've tried $_category->getThumbnailUrl();, but that doesn't appear to work. It seems pretty easy to get a product thumbnail, but for some reason categories are a little trickier. Does anyone know how to get a smaller version of the category image?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no native helper that produces thumbnail for category images. You need to create one for the category entity. To do that first create helper class in `Helper\Category\Image.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Helper\Category;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as CatalogImage;
use Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\Image as ImageModel;
use Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\ImageFactory as ImageModelFactory;

class Image extends CatalogImage
{
    /**
     * Current Product
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $_category;

    /**
     * Product image factory
     *
     * @var \Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryImageFactory;


    /**
     * Current model
     *
     * @var ImageModel
     */
    protected $_model;

    /**
     * Image constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory $productImageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface $viewConfig
     * @param ImageModelFactory $categoryImageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory $productImageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface $viewConfig,
        ImageModelFactory $categoryImageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryImageFactory = $categoryImageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $productImageFactory, $assetRepo, $viewConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Reset all previous data
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _reset()
    {
        $this->_category = null;
        return parent::_reset();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize Helper to work with Image
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @param string $imageId
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function init($category, $imageId, $attributes = ['type' => 'image'])
    {
        $this->_reset();

        $this->attributes = array_merge(
            $this->getConfigView()->getMediaAttributes('Magento_Catalog', self::MEDIA_TYPE_CONFIG_NODE, $imageId),
            $attributes
        );

        $this->setCategory($category);
        $this->setImageProperties();
        $this->setWatermarkProperties();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Override getProduct method for use in the parent class
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->getCategory();
    }

    /**
     * Set current Product
     *
     * @param Category $category
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->_category = $category;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get current Product
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    protected function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->_category;
    }

    /**
     * Get current Image model
     *
     * @return ImageModel
     */
    protected function _getModel()
    {
        if (!$this->_model) {
            $this->_model = $this->_categoryImageFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }
}
```

Then you need to create `Model\Category\Image.php` with the following code

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Category;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image as ProductImage;
use Magento\Framework\Image as MagentoImage;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config as MediaConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\View\FileSystem as ViewFileSystem;
use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;

class Image extends ProductImage
{
    /**
     * Catalog product media config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config
     */
    protected $_catalogProductMediaConfig;

    /**
     * Image constructor.
     * @param Media\Config $mediaConfig
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param MediaConfig $catalogProductMediaConfig
     * @param Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param MagentoImage\Factory $imageFactory
     * @param Repository $assetRepo
     * @param ViewFileSystem $viewFileSystem
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Media\Config $mediaConfig,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        MediaConfig $catalogProductMediaConfig,
        Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        MagentoImage\Factory $imageFactory,
        Repository $assetRepo,
        ViewFileSystem $viewFileSystem,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $storeManager, $catalogProductMediaConfig, $coreFileStorageDatabase, $filesystem, $imageFactory, $assetRepo, $viewFileSystem, $scopeConfig, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);

        //override models for product image with our custom ones
        $this->_catalogProductMediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
        $this->_mediaDirectory->create($this->_catalogProductMediaConfig->getBaseMediaPath());
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        if ($this->_newFile === true) {
            $url = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl(
                "Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/{$this->getDestinationSubdir()}.jpg"
            );
        }
        else {
            $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                ) . $this->_newFile;
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

and finally model for configuration in `Model\Category\Media\Config.php`

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\Media;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config as MediaConfig;

class Config extends MediaConfig
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseMediaUrl()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/category';
    }

    /**
     * Filesystem directory path of product images
     * relatively to media folder
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseMediaPathAddition()
    {
        return 'catalog/category';
    }

    /**
     * Web-based directory path of product images
     * relatively to media folder
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseMediaUrlAddition()
    {
        return 'catalog/category';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseMediaPath()
    {
        return 'catalog/category';
    }
}
```

Now in the template file you can inject `Vendor\Extension\Helper\Category\Image` and resize category image using:

```
echo $categoryHelperImage->init($categoryModel, 'image')->resize(100,100)->getUrl();
```

Comment: Bummer, that's what I figured. Thanks for the code snippets @Zefiryn

Comment: How work : use Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\ImageFactory as ImageModelFactory ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand this your comment.

Comment: easy! magento2 always the best :)

Comment: @Zefiryn Thanks for the solution. but `Vendor\Extension\Model\Category\ImageFactory` seems undefined?

Comment: Factories are created by di compile or on the fly in dwveloper mode